# Create an array 1*3 containing only one 1 and rest 0

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am just learning matlab now. I faced a difficulty in creating an array of 3 elements in a row.
I wrote a code

Source = randi ([0,1],1,3);

which gave me output

[1,1,0].....
[0,1,1]....

but I was willing to get only one 1 and two zeros in the output instead of getting two 1 and one zero.
I know I am wrong because I am using **randi** function and gives random value of 0 & 1 and output I get can be [0,0,1] ... [1,0,0]... too.

My clear problem is to only get only one 1 if I repeat as many times. e.g. I should get only [0,0,1] or [0,1,0] or [1,0,0].

Hope I can get solution.
Thank you.
Ujwal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way using [`randperm`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
n = 3; %// total number of elements
m = 1; %// number of ones
x = [ones(1,m) zeros(1,n-m)];
x = x(randperm(numel(x)));
```

Comment: Great, it works well. And I performed with 10 iterations.
for i = 1:10;
    n = 3;
    m = 1;
    Source = [ones(1,m) zeros(1,n-m)];
    Destination = [ones(1,m) zeros(1,n-m)];
    Source = Source(randperm(numel(Source)));
    Destination = Destination(randperm(numel(Destination)));
end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of alternative solutions for your problem.

Create zero-filled matrix and set random element to one:

```
x = zeros(1, 3);
x(randi(3)) = 1;
```

Create `1x3` `eye` matrix and randomly `circshift` it:

```
x = circshift(eye(1,3), [0, randi(3)]);
```

Comment: it was useful and gives perfect output.